# Is it possible to set the JVM working directory on startup?

Tags: java, jvm, java-native-interface

I'm using JNI to startup a JVM and I can't figure out how to set the working directory. I've tried

```
options[1].optionString = "-Duser.dir=directory";
vm_args.options = options;
```

as part of my JNI_CreateJavaVM args, but it doesn't work. The user.dir system property is set to what I specified in my parameters, but the actual relative directory used by things like FileReader is the same directory as whatever I use to call the dll. Is there any way to tell the JVM where the cwd should be on startup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could call 'chdir()', but it isn't advisable for programs other than the shell to do so. Just change the current directory yourself in the shell before you start it.

Comment: Thanks, I called chdir before I invoked JVM and it used that directory for relative paths. I don't execute my dll through the shell so I can't change it there.

Answer (score 1):

Since the JVM isn't started as its own executable, your working directory is where your base application is running.

Comment: What do you mean by "isn't started as its own executable"?

Comment: He's loading it within another application via `JNI_CreateJavaVM`, so it inherits that application's environment, e.g. working directory.  In this case, he's loading a dll which is then calling `JNI_CreateJavaVM`, so the working directory is wherever the dll is.